# Unable to download the .7z extension file through application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-8, 7zip

Am trying to download the .7z file using our website application.But it shows the below error.

HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map
can anyone suggest me how can I resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Nithya G

Comment: Show us your download code.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to set the MIME type on the server:

application/x-7z-compressed

How to set MIME Types on IIS:
http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap

Comment: Thanks for the response...I set the MIME type on the iis server already but it again shows this error..

Comment: I would suggest double checking what you did.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example using a button:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM";
    String Header = "Attachment; Filename=x.7z";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", Header);
    System.IO.FileInfo Dfile = new System.IO.FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/x.7z"));
    Response.WriteFile(Dfile.FullName);
    //Don't forget to add the following line
    Response.End();

}
```

In IIS you may want to set the MIME type as so:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

along with setting up `MIME` type, you also need to add a new `Managed Handler`, with `Request Path` set to `*.7z` Second method in [THIS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/544289/Restricting-files-download-using-HTTP-Handler-base) article will help you regarding how to do this

Answer (score 0):

You need to add relevant mime types to IIS on your server.